# PostgreSQL - casting varchar to int?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID>9;
```

But i can't since the 'ID' field is of type 'varchar'.
How can i cast it to 'int' and have it act properly? (deleting all rows with `ID` greater than 9 rather than converting it to a numeric `varchar` value)

Comment: `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID::int > 9;`

Comment: If you forsee a need to treat `ID` as a number, then consider storing it in a numeric column, not as text.

Comment: Trying your first solution i get invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Comment: The cast should work.  Maybe you are doing something else or maybe you are using a really old version of Postgres.  Let me post an answer.

Comment: It's because you have empty values on the column... and empty is not a number.

Comment: Warning, If your columns ID contains non-numeric values, you can't cast in numeric !

Comment: I checked and i don't have empty values in this column. Even when i do 'WHERE ID = 9' it doesn't work.

Comment: To escape empty values (or any other) you can use `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE coalesce(cast(nullif(id,'') as integer),0)>9`. There you cast as null any empty (change the '' for 'x' if you have other string issues) and then cast it as 0 with the coalesce. But you should check the column, since it is varchar, it could contain any character that cannot be integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you would store a numeric value as a string.  You might want something more like:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
    WHERE regexp_matches(ID, '^[1-9][0-9]');
```

This will delete from the table any `id` that starts with two digits, where the first is not `0`.  If you attempt a conversion, then you might get a conversion error if not all ids are numbers.  This will also work for long numbers that would overflow an int (although `numeric` would fix that problem).

EDIT:

For a general solution, I think I would write it as:

```
where (case when regexp_matches(id, '^[0-9]+$')
            then id::numeric
       end) > 70000
```

The `case` should prevent any error on non-numeric `id`s.

Comment: I'm working on somebody else's project, not mine. I didn't really understand your solution, how can i generalize it? Like 'WHERE ID > 70000'